# Rails - instance_method_already_implemented causing issue while displaying the value of field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've used `model_name` as a field name which is causing an error

> model_name is defined by Active Record. Check to make sure that you don't have an attribute or method with the same name.

I looked at other similar question on SO and tried overriding the `instance_method_already_implemented` method as below

```
class << self
  def instance_method_already_implemented?(method_name)
   return true if method_name == 'model_name'       
   super
  end
end
```

and also tried using the gem named `safe_attributes`. The only diff in using the gem was that I did not need to used the above method as it intends.

I'm facing issues while displaying the value of this column. When I implement either of the above two, the value for the field is the name of the Model in which its present. In my case, `Machinery`.

If I use `return false` in the above class method, I get the error saying `undefined method`param_key' for "xyz":String`while on the edit page where`xyz` is a value for the model_name column for that record but the value is correctly displayed on the index page.

I'm not sure how to proceed with this error. Any guidance will be helpful. Please let me know if any other details are required.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why don't you just rename your column? AR use `model_name`  method internally. I think that it is not possible (or really very hard to do) to  name  column `model_name`. That is the reason why AR creator decide to throw exception and inform programmer about it.

Comment: @Piotr Galas, I understand that this is used by Active Record but as in the other questions, I think there would definitely be a way to override it. I just can't find one that would help me.